# Call php function from javascript and send parameter

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to send 'ID' to JS function then send the same ID again from JS function to php function.
Please tell me what is the wrong in my code!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteclient(ID){    //I receive the ID correctly until now!
var x = "<?php deleteclient11('ID');?>";
return false;
}
</script>

<?php
function deleteclient11($x)
{
echo "$x";
}
?>
```

Comment: The only wany I know to send data to php from js is `AJAX`

Comment: Why do so many people seem to think you can just call PHP functions in JavaScript...?

Comment: WHat you are doing here could possibly cause an irreversible rip in the time-space fabric. Try doing some research on **AJAX** and how to use it with PHP and Javascript.

Comment: @DevlshOne Too funny!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use AJAX, it's easy with jQuery or another library, so I'll demonstrate with jQuery.

**javascript**

```
var deleteClient = function(id) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'path/to/php/file',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {id:id},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data); // Inspect this in your console
        }
    });
};
```

**php file**

```
<?php

    if (isset($_POST['id'])) {

        deleteClient11($_POST['id']);

        function deleteClient11($x) {
           // your business logic
        }

    }

?>
```

More info: [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)