# Problems calling PHP function from Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

[Solved] check out the link by Jonathan M

**Reason**: SimpleHTTPServer doesn't handle POST

**Other tips**: I ran into another issue where the server was returning the entire .php file, instead of the value. This is because **python server doesn't handle php by default**. An easy get-around was to spin up a php server via `php -S youraddress:port`

---

I'm having problems calling php functions from javascript. I have tried some of the suggestions on stackoverflow without any success. I'm not sure what I'm missing here...

I'm writing to submit a simple POST request to my php file, but I get this error in my browser console:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/myphp.php 501 (Unsupported method ('POST'))
```

I'm writing a single page web app that is currently running on my local machine with a simple server running at /projecthome/

```
 python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

My files are laid out like this:

```
/projecthome/index.html
/projecthome/myphp.php
/projecthome/js/myjs.js
```

index.html:

```
...
<script src="js/myjs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        run();
    });
</script>
...
```

myjs.js:

```
function schemaCreationTool() {
var id='someID';

$.ajax({
    url: 'myphp.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {id:id},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
}
```

myphp.php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    select($_POST['id']);
}

function select($x) {
    echo "The select function is called.";
}
}
```

I followed solutions from these posts:

[calling a php function in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323518/calling-a-php-function-in-javascript)

[Call php function from javascript and send parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19149166/call-php-function-from-javascript-and-send-parameter)

Comment: What's in redirect.php?

Comment: What is running on port 8000?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP or Javascript.  You're running Python's `SimpleHTTPServer`, which doesn't support POST requests.  Switch to a web server that does.

Comment: redirect.php is actually myphp.php (edited all of my file names for this post) sorry for the confusion. It's been corrected. 

localhost:8000 is running a simpleHTTPServer, which loads index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python's SimpleHTTPServer doesn't natively support POSTs. You can extended it to do so with this little handler:

http://georgik.sinusgear.com/2011/01/07/how-to-dump-post-request-with-python/